# form.isFieldValidating not working in ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

i'm using next js

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();

const onFinishFailed = ({ values }) => {    
 console.log("email-status",form.isFieldValidating('email'),form.getFieldsError())
 console.log("failed",values);
};

<Form
   {...layout}
   layout="vertical"
   name="basic"
   form = {form}
   initialValues={{ email: "",password: "",remember: true,}}
   onFinish={onFinish}
   onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
 >

<Form.Item
  name="email"
  label="E-mail"
  rules={[
          {
            type: 'email',
            message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
          },
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
          },
        ]}
 >
  <Input />
</Form.Item>

<Form.Item
  name="password"
  label="Password"
   rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your password!',
          },
        ]}
      
 >
   <Input.Password />
 </Form.Item>

<Form.Item >
   <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
       Register
    </Button>
</Form.Item>
```

Now when I type a valid email and doesn't enter a password and click on Register button

a) I'm getting 'Please input your password!',and not getting any error displayed under email input box     // which is expected

b) Since i haven't entered any password on clicking the registered button
"onFinishFailed " function is being  executed      // so far so good

c) But in console I'm getting the output as

```
email-status, false, []
```

It should be  **email-status , true, [ ]**  right...